# Tried to fix "gpg: WARNING unsafe warning on homedir" but it went very wrong

Tags: permissions, gnupg

I got this error:

```
gpg: warning: unsafe ownership on homedir '/home/prime/.gnupg'
```

I first got this error when installing a browser from the command line. So I searched for instructions regarding this `gpg: warning`.

I followed the instructions to list `.gnupg` and then used `--kill` on any showing `root:root` like this:

```
sudo gpgconf --kill pubring.kbx
```

It returned:

```
Component not found
```

I then performed:

```
chown $(whoami):$(whoami) ~/.gnupg
```

It returned `total 48` so  I listed once more the contents the directory:

```
ls -l ~/.gnupg
```

All previous 7 files with `root:root` permissions were still showing as `root:root`.

So I continued with the instructions and performed:

```
chmod 600 ~/.gnupg
```

Now all I get is `permission denied`, no matter what I do.

I know I messed up, but I don't know what to do now.

Comment: `chown $(whoami):$(whoami) ~/.gnupg` looks good, but only affects the directory itself and not its contents. Using the `-R` option would make the `chown` command **R**ecursive, in other words it would go into the directory as well and would change all those root ownerships to you instead. Also, without `sudo`, it will not be able to give something that's currently root's, to you. That's why, in this case, you need to run it with sudo. So that would be `sudo chown -R $(whoami):$(whoami) ~/.gnupg`

Comment: Yea!  That did it.... no more root root just me user user :)  Thank You...

Comment: Do I mark this as answered?  Or does that happen some other way?

Comment: This is a comment, that can't be marked too well. If I added the same text as an answer, you could then mark it. But before, I would like to ask: does your gpg utility work as intended now? Any remaining glitches?

Comment: Also, if you could add the story of how this directory could have ended up in the ownership of root in the firs place (that is not typical) (perhaps you have used `sudo` somewhere where it was not supposed to be?), that could be upvote-worthy (for educative purposes).

Answer (score 2):

You need to run:

```
chown -R $(whoami) ~/.gnupg/
chmod 600 ~/.gnupg/*
chmod 700 ~/.gnupg
```

I found this gist gives a helpful description about what each command is doing: https://gist.github.com/oseme-techguy/bae2e309c084d93b75a9b25f49718f85

If your .gnupg directory is currently owned by root, then you'll need to prepend the first command with `sudo`.

Comment: This messed up permissions on osx